# Is it possible to modify the layers of the models present in the Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I would like to know if there is any way in which we can change the base layers of the models offered by the Tensorflow Object Detection API and if so, is it possible to change things like pooling/padding size, number of layers and also hyperparameters like optimizer used, initial weights and the learning rate.